# Ignore blank cells in my Excel INDEX formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

I have the following table on Excel from **A2-A10**

```
YEAR
1999
1997

1999
1998
1998

1996
1999
```

=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$10)),COLUMN((A1)))     >>> (drag formula horizontally)

This is my output:

```
1996  1997 1998 1999 0
```

The problem is that it keeps returning 0 because my range contains some blank cells. How can I ignore blanks using this formula?

Comment: Try adding ifblank() or if > 0 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three possibilities:

```
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE(IF($A$2:$A$10<>"",$A$2:$A$10,LARGE($A$2:$A$10;1)))),COLUMN((A1)))
```

```
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10<>""))),COLUMN((A1)))
```

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$10)),COLUMN((A1)))),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or skipping INDEX so you don't need to drag your formula to the right:
`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10<>""))))`